# Add git project to GitHub that is on GitLab, keep separate

Tags: git, github, gitlab

**I'd like to take my existing repo on GitLab `Questions` and upload it to GitHub.**

I want the repo's to be the same project/files, but two act as if they are two different repo's.  So I wouldn't want pushing to origin master from the GitLab project folder to the repo to effect anything from the GitHub project folder.

**I want to keep the projects/folders completely separate**.  But I basically want to copy the project as it is now and just upload it to GitHub, and not effect anything on GitLab or vice-a-versa.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all in the same directory by adding a second remote origin, if you've already added Gitlab as 'origin', then run:

```
git remote add github https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

then you can push up your changes you've made to the two repos

to push to GitLab:

```
git push origin
```

and then to push to GitHub

```
git push github
```

See this [github doc page](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/)